# show/hide div after selecting a radio button

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm trying to show a div with diffent text after a radio button is selected and hide all the other divs.

```
<?php
foreach ($items as $item){
$i=1;

echo '
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio1" id="detail_variant'.$i.'" >
       <label class="form-check-label">'.$item['title'].'</label>
</div>';

$detail_variant_html.="
<div id='detail_variant".$i."'>
  <p> size: ".$item['size'."<br>
  Color: ".$item['color']."<br>
  Garment:".$item['garment']."
  </p>
</div>";
$i++;

}
echo ' <div class="card-body">'.echo $detail_variant_html.'  </div>';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing `i` in every iteration of loop that makes it `=1` always.

and as you needed the division with different text should visible on radio button so I edit it like this...

```
<?php
$i=1;
foreach ($items as $item){
echo '
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio1" id="detail_variant" onchange="showdiv('.$i.');">
       <label class="form-check-label">'.$item['title'].'</label>
</div>';

//initially hide all
$detail_variant_html.="
<div style='display:none' id='detail_variant".$i."'> 
  <p> size: ".$item['size'."<br>
  Color: ".$item['color']."<br>
  Garment:".$item['garment']."
  </p>
</div>";
$i++;

}
echo ' <div class="card-body">'.echo $detail_variant_html.'  </div>';
    ?>
<script>
function showdiv(n){
var div = "detail_variant" + n;
document.getElementById("div").style.display='';//show only division you want
}
</script>
```

Note:- once the division is displayed it I am not hiding in the above code, you can hide it if you want.
If this worked give me feedback also If you have error tell me.

Comment: Hi! this work fine, i just change this part 

document.getElementById(div).style.display='';

Now i need hide all the other elements and just display the selected

Comment: Ok so the one you select(radio) works fine?, now what else you want..? I will try to help you.

Comment: @Kahmra You can do some tweaks with the script to hide/show the divisions, once you show the division on radio button again hide it with select of other radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You can define in a jquery that if the radio button clicked, your desire div (call with id) to be hidden.

And by checked radio button, you can use `hide()` method of js to disapear it in your page

For example:

```
if(document.getElementById('detail_variant').checked) {
   $('#detail_variant').hide();
}
```